# Wordpress root directory issue

Tags: php, wordpress, hosting, blogs, root

I had a site setup on a test domain and hosting. I then moved it to its actual domain and hosting account, and made all the changed needed for this to be a success.

I now have an issue of the media upload not working. The strange thing is that the error makes reference to the old root directory.

```
 /home/wwwOLD/public_html/wp-content/uploads/image1.tmp because No such file or directory in /home/wwwNEW/public_html/wp-admin/includes/file.php on line 178
```

Is there any reason why it would make reference to that old home directory, as I cannot see it in the database anywhere, or in any  configs.

Comment: It'll be there somewhere. Probably some obscure database entry. Try a wordpress forum for a quick answer.

Comment: What does it say on line 178 of file.php?

Comment: It is somehow still pointing to the old temp directory :/

Comment: Where is it getting $filename?

Comment: wordpress function

function wp_tempnam($filename = '', $dir = '') {
 if ( empty($dir) )
  $dir = get_temp_dir();
 $filename = basename($filename);
 if ( empty($filename) )
  $filename = time();

 $filename = preg_replace('|\..*$|', '.tmp', $filename);
 $filename = $dir . wp_unique_filename($dir, $filename);
 touch($filename);
 return $filename;
}

Answer (score 0):

If you transferred the files rather than starting over from scratch, the configuration file was maintained which contains the location files should be uploaded to.

You should reinstall wordpress from scratch after making a backup of your database.

Comment: Reinstalling is not an option. If you knew which file to change, that would answer the question for me.

Comment: please post line 178 on file.php in the OP

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered that many times before in the past when moving wp sites.
This is how I fixed them:

Go to your wp-admin / settings / media and update the field
**Store uploads in this folder**

Either put blank there or put **wp-content/uploads**

Comment: I have tried this. Just confused where it is storing the old reference?

Comment: If its blank and if its still using the old reference, you will need the wp-content/uploads then. it should work after that settings.

Comment: ah, you might need chmod that uploads folder. Are you hosted on linux?  chmod, or chown  http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions

Comment: it already has the correct permissons. The error is in referencing an old directory.

Comment: You have the latest version of WP right?  Could you re-upload the wp-admin, wp-includes and the wp-* files in rootfolder, just so it replace/renews the your installation.  Just incase that you got hacked, it will be cleaned up.